# How much hard drive space would I need for a Linux installation?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, disk-space, storage

New to Linux. Interested in learning more about it.

I currently have an SSD with Windows and a 1 TB RAID 1 setup. I'd like to add another SSD with Linux so I can dual boot but I'm not sure how large my new hard drive would be. Would I be safe with a 120 GB SSD or is it better to go with a 240 GB? I don't plan to store anything but programs and settings because all of my data would be on the RAID setup. I've maxed out my 240 GB SSD on Windows with all of my programs, etc. so I am wondering if I may run into the same issue with Linux eventually. I am just not sure how much space the system files generally take up compared to Windows, programs, etc. Thanks for any input.

Comment: What are you planning to do on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what programs you install, but in general Linux system files take up much less space than Windows. An Arch Linux base installation is easily much less than 5 GB (I don't remember precisely, but that's a good upper bound), while in my experience Windows installations have been in the range of 20-30 GB, which is certainly much larger.

Now of course if you want to install large programs in Linux like MATLAB, Mathematica, Civilization V, etc., then the required size will increase, so it's up to you to see how much you really need. However, my current Arch Linux installation isn't even close to using up the 112 GB I've allocated for the partition, so I think 120 GB is more than enough if you're just experimenting with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It is great that you are new to linux, but it is too general question, and lack of details.

1. Wich Linux do you want to install?
2. What other programs you want to install within?

Programs for Windows and for linux **are roughly same size***. Not Linux and Windows!!
So if you can go on Windowos with **240gb - Windows instalation size** , you can go with **240GB - Linux instalation size**

Answer (score 0):

120 GB should be plenty as long as you are not storing your video or music collection on there.  However, if the price break is less than $30, then just get the bigger drive (my 2 cents).  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

i have dual boot my windows 8 with linux mint and 80GB disk space was more than enough for me. I have stored my programs, projects and other college work in it